# MYSQL - Fetch records between two dates using GROUP BY and INNER JOIN from one table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, inner-join

I have a below table:

```sql
SELECT * FROM dashboard.reports WHERE date='2020-04-06';
```

```
+------+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| # id |     date     | type     | quantity |  vendor  |
+------+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| '11' | '2020-04-06' | '2520'   | '150'    | 'vendor1'  |
| '12' | '2020-04-06' | 'HG851'  | '200'    | 'vendor2' |
| '13' | '2020-04-06' | 'HG851'  | '200'    | 'vendor2' |
| '14' | '2020-04-06' | 'HG851A' | '400'    | 'vendor2' |
+------+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I have to calculate the quantity column's total by GROUP BY vendor for the particular day. So below is my query:

```sql
SELECT a.date, a.vendor, a.type, a.quantity, b.total FROM dashboard.reports a 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT vendor, SUM(quantity) as total FROM dashboard.reports WHERE date = '2020-04-06' GROUP BY vendor
) b 
ON b.vendor = a.vendor WHERE date = '2020-04-06'
```

Result: (Here the total is for the date '2020-04-06')

```
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+-------+
|    # date    |  vendor  | type | quantity | total |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+-------+
| '2020-04-0'  | 'vendor1'  | '2520'   | '150'    | '150' |
| '2020-04-06' | 'vendor2' | 'HG851'  | '200'    | '800' |
| '2020-04-06' | 'vendor2' | 'HG851'  | '200'    | '800' |
| '2020-04-06' | 'vendor2' | 'HG851A' | '400'    | '800' |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+-------+
```

vendor1 Total ---> 150
vendor2 Total (200 + 200 + 400) ----> 800

The above result is working as expected for one particular day. However, if I want to get records between two dates... I am not sure how to write a query. I have tried below one, but the total I am getting for all days. I want the quantity column's total for each day separately.

```sql
SELECT a.date, a.vendor, a.type, a.quantity, b.total FROM dashboard.reports a 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT vendor, SUM(quantity) as total FROM dashboard.reports WHERE  date >= '2020-04-06' AND date <= '2020-04-08' GROUP BY vendor
) b 
ON b.vendor = a.vendor WHERE date >= '2020-04-06' AND date <= '2020-04-08'
```

```
+--------------+----------+-------------+----------+---------+
|    # date    |  vendor  |  type   | quantity |  total  |
+--------------+----------+-------------+----------+---------+
| '2020-04-06' | 'vendor1'  | '2520'      | '150'    | '1250'  |
| '2020-04-06' | 'vendor2' | 'HG851'     | '200'    | '1400'  |
| '2020-04-06' | 'vendor2' | 'HG851'     | '200'    | '1400'  |
| '2020-04-06' | 'vendor2' | 'HG851A'    | '400'    | '1400'  |
| '2020-04-07' | 'vendor1'  | '2511'      | '200'    | '1250'  |
| '2020-04-07' | 'vendor1'  | '5120'      | '350'    | '1250'  |
| '2020-04-07' | 'vendor1'  | '2520'      | '150'    | '1250'  |
| '2020-04-07' | 'vendor1'  | '5114'      | '400'    | '1250'  |
| '2020-04-07' | 'vendor3'  | 'G-440G-A'  | '200'    | '20750' |
| '2020-04-07' | 'vendor3'  | '1240GA'    | '400'    | '20750' |
| '2020-04-07' | 'vendor3'  | '1440GP'    | '9000'   | '20750' |
| '2020-04-07' | 'vendor3'  | 'B-0404G-B' | '7000'   | '20750' |
| '2020-04-07' | 'vendor3'  | 'B2404GP'   | '2000'   | '20750' |
| '2020-04-07' | 'vendor3'  | 'G-881G-A'  | '2000'   | '20750' |
| '2020-04-08' | 'vendor3'  | 'G-881G-B'  | '150'    | '20750' |
| '2020-04-08' | 'vendor2' | 'HG851'     | '200'    | '1400'  |
| '2020-04-08' | 'vendor2' | 'HG851A'    | '400'    | '1400'  |
+--------------+----------+-------------+----------+---------+
```

Can someone help me with this? If the queries I wrote above are completely wrong please guide me on how to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the date as well. Ie: "Group by vendor, date"

Comment: I tried... but getting duplicate records. 

# date, vendor, ont_type, quantity, total
1. '2020-04-06', 'ZHONE', '2520', '150', '150'
2. '2020-04-06', 'ZHONE', '2520', '150', '1100'
3. '2020-04-06', 'HUAWEI', 'HG851', '200', '800'
4. '2020-04-06', 'HUAWEI', 'HG851', '200', '600'

Comment: SELECT a.date, a.vendor, a.ont_type, a.quantity, b.total FROM dashboard.reports a 
INNER JOIN 
(
 SELECT vendor, SUM(quantity) as total FROM dashboard.reports WHERE  date >= '2020-04-06' AND date <= '2020-04-08' GROUP BY vendor, date
) b 
ON b.vendor = a.vendor WHERE date >= '2020-04-06' AND date <= '2020-04-08'

Comment: Try doing the join on the date as well as the vendor as well.

Comment: On a.vendor =b.vendor and a.date =b.date